# The Minimized Dropmate

Tags: chess, optimization

I don't know, but I think my opponent just *may* be cheating in this chess game.

[image]

So, the natural thing to do is cheat right back! My plan is to put black pieces on the board so the white king is immediately checkmated.

However, I need to put the pieces with the lowest total value (pawn = 1, knight/bishop = 3, rook = 5, queen = 9) on the board to checkmate the king.

So, the question is:

**What is the lowest total value of black pieces you can 'drop' on the board to immediately checkmate the white king here?**

Some other rules:

> - Normal piece counts don't apply. Go wild with 10 pawns, 5 knights, 4 rooks, etc.
> - Legal double checks are allowed; triple checks aren't.
> - You may only drop black pieces, not additional white ones.

Good luck!

Comment: What does "*legal* double checks" mean?

Comment: what about the black king?

Comment: @RomanOdaisky feel free to ignore the king, and I'm not allowing it in the puzzle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt this is minimal but I can do it with

> 1+3+9=13 "points": Qh5 supported by Pg6, and Nd5 to cover the other two squares the WK can move to.

[EDITED to add:] Better:

> 1+1+1+1+1+3 = 8 "points": pawns on {g,h}{6,7} and h5, plus bishop on g3.

Comment: and what was black’s last move?

Comment: I don't think there are *moves* in this scenario: this doesn't need to be a position that can legally be reached, or anything like that. ("10 pawns", "feel free to ignore the [black] king", etc.)

Comment: you could move things around a bit (4Q3/4Qpp1/4Q1pp/4Q1Kp/4Q3/4Q1b1/4Q3/4Q3) though. And I think it can’t be improved (pawns can’t attack h4 so you need at least one minor piece, and no more than two pawns can attack two relevant squares).

Comment: Yeah, that’s it. 8 is the minimum as far as I can tell.

Comment: For what it's worth, it feels minimal to me too for the reasons Roman gives.

Comment: Last move was "drop pawn in h6,checkmate". Black king should be in h7, totalling 7 points instead of 8.

Comment: I think if you're going to allow the BK to participate then it needs to be allocated a nonzero cost.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on all possible solutions..

> 8 points as previously mentioned
>  There are three mutually exclusive things that can change (the 7th rank, 5th rank, and g file), with two possibilities each. There are 3 binary choices, with the same number of possibilities as 111 in binary, which is 7.
>  https://lichess.org/study/08jnWWTX